# I Can't add MySQL AFTER INSERT Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got some trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE
    TRIGGER `auto_user_auth` AFTER INSERT
    ON `tbl_user`
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            INSERT INTO authassignment(itemname, userid) VALUES ('Customer', NEW.id);
        END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

There is no error on query that in PhpMyAdmin, but after that on query:

```
DROP TRIGGER `auto_user_auth`
```

I'm getting:

> ## 1360 - Trigger does not exist

Without `DELIMETER ;` I'm getting:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

What's I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for help

Comment: `DELIMETER ;` just changes the end of statement delimiter back to a semi-colon as at the beginning you change it to `$$`

Comment: Well, `DELIMETER` has a spelling error. I don't know what a Deli-meter measures :)

Comment: Sorry, I used DELIMITER in my example and I just writted wrong on StackOverflow.

Comment: btw, it worked for me using phpmyadmin (creating 2 tables, create trigger, drop trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Please try with database name like -

```
DROP TRIGGER database_name.auto_user_auth;
```

OR

Write **&&** sign into Delimiter inputbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `auto_user_auth` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO authassignment(itemname, userid) VALUES ('Customer', NEW.id);
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```